# How to Read Rss Feed By using java script

Tags: javascript, rss-reader

How to read RSS Feed by using Java Script.

As I am Android developer I am very new In Java Script I have basic knowledge That's why I have not tried any thing.

I just want to know is this possible to do by javascript if yes then any one please give me the basic idea so that I will start.

Below is my code that I have tried. But it is not working.

```
function latestQuaterly()
{
 alert("Onclick Event is occur");
 com.myjavatools.xml.Rss rss = new com.myjavatools.xml.Rss(new java.net.URL("http://219.64.5.9/androidwebservice/RssFeed.aspx?linkname=annualreport";)); 
 int increment = 0; 
 for (java.util.Iterator i = rss.getItems().iterator(); i.hasNext();)
  { 
    if (increment > 1) { 
        break; 
        } 
        increment++; 
        com.myjavatools.xml.Rss.Item item = (com.myjavatools.xml.Rss.Item) i.next();
   }
   alert("count is :"+increment);
 }
```

**In side the the RSS feed their is Title, Description and link I want to retrieve that separately .**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6929510/problem-parsing-rss-feed-using-javascript

Comment: The very first step should always be Googling. Questions like this *always* have thousands of good resources available for those who search. E.g. `javascript parse RSS` seems to yield good results. If you run into problems working with *those*, *that* will then be a good Stack Overflow question

Comment: @Pekka Thanks a lot for your Information.... I don't know that.....

Comment: That code looks like it starts out as JavaScript then tries to be Java, then goes back to JavaScript. You can't switch languages like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to do it in jsp file, you can write java code inside scriptlet tag and use the java rss library ----http://www.myjavatools.com/projects/v.1.4.2/xml/doc/com/myjavatools/xml/Rss.html

The library provide methods to read all feeds from the given url and supported methods to display each feed seperately.

Comment: @ChrisW Thanks a lot for your information. do you have any solution for Javascript. on the above question that I have asked. or you have just read the Tags.

Comment: here is the scriptlet code we are using in our application <%

        com.myjavatools.xml.Rss rss = new com.myjavatools.xml.Rss(new java.net.URL("http://xxx.com/feed/"));
        int increment = 0;
        for (java.util.Iterator i = rss.getItems().iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
            if (increment > 1) {
                break;
            }
            increment++;
            com.myjavatools.xml.Rss.Item item = (com.myjavatools.xml.Rss.Item) i.next();

    %>

Comment: given url is dummy one. pls use ur feed url there

Comment: @mini I am developing the android application. In that HTML5 and Java script will give the support. So by using above java script code can we read the Rss Feed.

Comment: sorry i am not aware of android but we used it in java application. u may find the way here--http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226663/parse-rss-with-jquery